# Перевод числа из двоичной системы в десятичную, c

Tags: c, системы-счисления

```
#include <stdio.h>  
 //Compiler version gcc 6.3.0  
 int power(int c, int d)  
 {  
    int p=1;  
    int g;  
    for (g=1;g<=d;g++)  
    p=p*c;  
    return p;  
 }  

 int main(void)  
 {  
    int i, j, counter;  
    int b[j];  
    char q;  
    char a[i];  
    while(scanf("%c", &q)==1){  
        if(q=='0'){  
            a[i]=0;   
            i++;  
            counter++;}  
        if(q=='1'){  
            a[i]=1;  
            i++;  
            counter++;}}        
    while(i>0)  
    {  
        b[j]=((a[counter-i])*power(2, (i-1)));  
        i--;  
        j++;  
    }  

    int x;  
    for(j=0;j<counter;j++)  
        x=x+b[j];  
    printf("%i\n", x);      
    return 0; 
 }
```

**Подскажите, где ошибка?**

Comment: Кстати `i`, `j`, `counter` не инициализированные используются, вначале нужно их занулить.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Binary to decimal in c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12338584/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А стоит ли так страшно?

```
int main(void)
{
    char q;
    int res = 0;
    while(scanf("%c", &q)==1)
    {
        if (q != '0' && q != '1')
        {
            if (q == '\n') break; // Конец ввода
        }
        res = res*2+(q-'0');
    }
    printf("%i\n", res);
}
```

Игнорируем все символы не 0 и не 1, по переводу строки завершаем работу.

Comment: Да, тут я облажался. Но всё-таки почему в программе получаю какие-то адреса, а не числа?

Comment: Да у вас все неинициализировано... Или вот - `int j; int b[j];` - что вы тут хотите? Есть **мусор** в переменной `j`, вы создаете массив с неизвестно каким количеством элементов... Как и `a[i]`. Мало того - вы еще сразу же начинаете писать **за пределами массива** - начиная с `a[i]` и увеличивая `i`. Такие программы проще не исправлять, а переписывать.

Answer (score 1):

Можно заметно упростить код, обрабатывая входную последовательность бит по одному:

1. встретив новый бит, наращиваем число на один бит, сдвигая его число влево (`n <<= 1` — умножение на `2`)
2. если новый бит установлен (единица), то дополнительно прибавляем `1`
3. любой другой символ во вводе (такой как новая строка `'\n'`) означает конец числа.

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  uintmax_t n = 0;
  for (int b; (b = getchar()) != EOF; ) {
    if (b == '1')
      n = 2*n + 1;
    else if (b == '0')
      n *= 2;
    else // end of the number
      break;
  }
  return printf("%ju\n", n) < 0;
}
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/M9MAWA):

```
$ cc *.c && echo 001100111000 | ./a.out
824
```

Чтобы поддерживать произвольное количество битов, можно gmp библиотеку использовать:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gmp.h>

int main(void)
{
  mpz_t n;
  mpz_init(n);
  size_t nread = mpz_inp_str(n, stdin, 2);
  size_t nwritten = nread ? mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, n) : 0;
  mpz_clear(n);
  return nwritten ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Пример:

```
$ cc *.c -lgmp && echo 00110011100011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 | ./a.out
280732952709774232357284051131208774451199
```