# найти сумму чисел в веденной строке

Tags: c, массивы

Стоит задача: написать программу, которая находит сумму чисел во введённой строке.Программа рассматривает непрерывные последовательности цифр в строке как числа и обрабатывает их как единое целое. В программе предусмотреть ограни- чение на максимальное число разрядов, то есть если пользователь вводит очень длинную последовательность цифр, её нужно разбить на несколько групп.

Пример:

"ab12cd45e" -> 57

Состав

Программа должна состоять из функций:

```
- int getSum(char buf[]) - нахождение суммы
- main().
```

Я написал программу , но она просто плюсует между собой стоящие подряд цифры.Как реализовать чтобы два числа считалось как цифра и суммировалась с остальными? Вот мой код:

```
# include  <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char  str[80], i = 0;
    int sum = 0;                                         
    puts("Enter  a string:");                
    fgets(str, 80, stdin);                                     
    while (str[i] && str[i] != '\n')                 
    {
        if (str[i] >= '0'  &&  str[i] <= '9')               
            sum += str[i] - '0';                              
        i++;                                         
    }

    printf("Sum=%d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На C, кстати, можно и в один проход, без разбиения на слова:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
static int my_sum(const char *src)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while (*src) {
        while (*src && !isdigit(*src))
            ++src;
        sum += atoi(src);
        while (*src && isdigit(*src))
            ++src;
    }

    return sum;
}

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int sum = my_sum("ab12cd45e");
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    return sum;
}

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

Или:

```
static int my_sum(const char *src)
{
    int sum = 0;
    char *endptr;
    while (*src) {
        while (*src && !isdigit(*src))
            ++src;
        sum += strtol(src, &endptr, 10);
        src = endptr;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Используй регулярку

```html
std::string line;
 std::regex reg("([-]?[\\d]+)");
 std::smatch res;

 long long int sum = 0;

 while(std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
  std::string::const_iterator ib = line.begin(), ie = line.end();
  for (; std::regex_search(ib, ie, res, reg); ib = res[0].second)
   sum += std::stoi(res[0].str());
 }

 std::cout << sum;
```

Comment: А на Си можно ?

Comment: @Andrey97, можно. Принцип тот же: 1) разбейте строку на слова (разделитель слов - не-цифра) 2) переводите слова в числа (в стандартной библиотеке C для этого есть масса функций) 3) складывайте.

Comment: Спасибо большое , алгоритм понятен, буду реализовывать)

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum_numbers(const char *s) {
  int sum = 0, n = 0;
  for ( ; s && *s; ++s) {
    if ('0' <= *s && *s <= '9')
      n = n * 10 + (*s - '0');
    else if (n) { // complete number
      sum += n;
      n = 0;
    }
  }
  return sum + n;
}
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/20GJ04).

Comment: А как сделать ограничение на максимальное число разрядов, если пользователь вводит очень длинную последовательность цифр, её нужно разбить на несколько групп?

Comment: Если вы хотите целые с бесконечным количеством цифр поддерживать, то можно gmp библиотеку использовать. [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/749285/23044).

Comment: Я хочу если больше трех цифр то он их перебрасывал в другой разряд бы

Comment: я не понимаю, что значит "другой разряд"

Comment: ну допустим я ввожу kdksafj2345sdlf54 и у нас должно быть ограничение сколько цифр считать за число 23+45+54=122 должно получиться

Comment: за число мы должны считать только две или три цифры идущие подряд,если их больше , то это считается уже как другое число